# (colorPrimaryDark) status bar color not working on android v21?

Tags: android

I have added colorPrimaryDark on style.xml but no color affected on status bar android v21.

i have a custom toolbar where i use no action bar theme in style.xml code

if any solution please help me ?

style code:-

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="myCustomToolbarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

style v21 :-

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Toolbar Code:-

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="56dp"
android:elevation="4dp"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:popupTheme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

Main Layout Code

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/custom_toolbar"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button1" />

</LinearLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_plus"
    android:onClick="fabClick"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin_bottom"
    fab:borderWidth="0dp"/>
```

Answer (score 15):

I think your CoordinatorLayout is missing the following attribute: ***android:fitsSystemWindows="true"***

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
```

Comment: Thank god. You just saved my day. *fist bump*

Comment: I think I had accidentally removed this property while doing some layout changes. Been searching for the past couple of hours for this solution.

Answer (score 12):

Long time ago now but I'll answer anyway, you should remove this line:

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

It's overriding the `colorPrimaryDark` color and basically removing it from the status bar.

Comment: Its not overriding. If you add android:statusBarColor then it won't override colorPrimaryDark.

Comment: what can I do if I want to override the colorPrimaryDark?

Answer (score 2):

Create a new styles.xml file in values-v21 and add following property in AppTheme.

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
```

I'm having following AppTheme in styles.xml (v21)

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Though this solution works, it overrides a statusbar color. So, if you have a navigation drawer or CollapsingToolbarLayout, you will have a solid-color bar instead of image behind the statusbar.

Answer (score -2):

try use

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
}
```