# BottomNavigationView is not full width

Tags: android, material-design, bottom-sheet

I am working on an Android app and implementing `BottomNavigationView` from the design library. I have looked at many examples and I can't figure out what is wrong with my layout. The `BottomNavigationView` is not displayed as full width.

Another issue is the status bar color is not getting applied.

[image]

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- Include the toolbar -->
<include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
    app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

**Edit**:
Added solution for Status Color not being set

`android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`

[(colorPrimaryDark) status bar color not working on android v21?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666019/colorprimarydark-status-bar-color-not-working-on-android-v21/33729062#comment70073391_33729062)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

> The BottomNavigationView is not displayed as full width.

It is not supposed to.

According to [design guidelines](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html) the width of an action can vary between 80dp and 168dp. The two actions you have defined are not sufficient to fill the whole area horizontally.
(As a side note, also according to  guidelines the view should contain between three and five actions.)

If you want to fill the space behind the `BottomNavigationView`, you can set the background color of the view to be the same color as the items background:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
     android:background="@color/bottom_view_color"
     app:itemBackground="@color/bottom_view_color"

     // .... />
```

Comment: The Bottom Nav seems full width in Google Play Newstand, so I thought there was an issue with my layouts. I plan to add a third menu item soon.

Comment: @midhunhk Yes that is possible. I added solution for that. BUT Andy is correct, you should follow design specs.

Answer (score 40):

That is doable. But it will againts [default design specs](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html#bottom-navigation-usage), and I will suggest you to go with [default design specs](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html#bottom-navigation-usage).

---

> Now coming to my solution...

Define below dimensions into `dimens.xml`. These dimensions should be in `values`, `values-large`, `values-large-land`. And `600dp` can be increased to `1000dp` or more in `values-large`, `values-large-land`, if in tablet you are not seeing this change.

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_item_max_width" tools:override="true">600dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_active_item_max_width" tools:override="true">600dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

And thats it!!! Result will be like [image]

---

*It's not a mazic.*

> Why dimensions has been added with such name and value is 600dp

Both dimensions is being used by `BottomNavigationMenuView.java` (which is the class being used to represent menu in `BottomNavigationView`).
Below is code

```
public BottomNavigationMenuView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    ...
    mInactiveItemMaxWidth = res.getDimensionPixelSize(
            R.dimen.design_bottom_navigation_item_max_width);
    ....
    mActiveItemMaxWidth = res.getDimensionPixelSize(
            R.dimen.design_bottom_navigation_active_item_max_width);
    .....
}
```

Now these values is being used to create view with fixed width, as below

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    ....
    if (mShiftingMode) {
        final int inactiveCount = count - 1;
        final int activeMaxAvailable = width - inactiveCount * mInactiveItemMinWidth;
        final int activeWidth = Math.min(activeMaxAvailable, mActiveItemMaxWidth);
        final int inactiveMaxAvailable = (width - activeWidth) / inactiveCount;
        final int inactiveWidth = Math.min(inactiveMaxAvailable, mInactiveItemMaxWidth);
        ...
    } else {
        final int maxAvailable = width / count;
        final int childWidth = Math.min(maxAvailable, mActiveItemMaxWidth);
        .....
    }
    ....
}
```

To use value of `activeMaxAvailable` always, I set a dummy value to `mActiveItemMaxWidth` (in dimens above). So `activeWidth` will have
value of `activeMaxAvailable`. Same rule apply for `inactiveWidth`.

So when you build project, `design_bottom_navigation_item_max_width` and `design_bottom_navigation_active_item_max_width` defined
into *design-support-lib*, will be replaced by dimensions defined by us.

**Code verified on maximum supported options (5 max) also.**

Comment: i am facing the issue with bottom navigation 
in mobile Bottomtabs display perfect but when i tried in tablet  Bottomtabs display in center what the issue?

Comment: YOu need to declare dimens for tablets also. The value must be greater than value of handsets

Comment: Okay, but i used SDP library for universal designing perspective and it handle as per screen size still facing the same issue.

Comment: @Arbaz.in what value you have added for tablets?

Comment: i didn't add any value for TAB  actually i used SDP library which take care of it

Comment: Perfect!!! It works! Exactly what I've looked for! Thank you, it is very helpful!=)

Answer (score 17):

I suggest to only use

```
android:background="@color/bottom_view_color"
```

It will display the bar as full width and it will keep the ripple effect when the user clicks the items.

If you also add `app:itemBackground` you will lose the ripple effect.

In your case

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
    app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution:

```
app:itemHorizontalTranslationEnabled = "false"
```

which is default to true. This "expands" the items to fit the entire width.

Comment: this solutions worked fo me

Answer (score 2):

A bit of a late answer, but for whoever is still looking for a solution:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu_res"/>

    </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>
```

the `app:contentInsetStart="0dp"` fixes that random space on the left