# Bottom Navigation View not responsive

Tags: android, responsive, bottomnavigationview

I need that BottomNavigationView to be responsive. When I use a [Nexus 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmIro.png) it has the exact measurement, but with [Nexus 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kF0OP.png) it does not. Any idea?

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/selector"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `layout_height` attribute to **wrap_content** instead of **match_parent**:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" //modify this line
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/selector"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

because the height is matching_parent!! so it depends of how the parent is composed and adapting the views, for this case is better to have a fix value width or setup to wrap_content but then you have to take care of size of icons!

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the width not matching the parent, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41432902/bottomnavigationview-is-not-full-width). You have to play with the background by setting its color with the same color as the item

```
 android:background="@color/bottom_view_color"
 app:itemBackground="@color/bottom_view_color"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `BottomNavigationView` height as `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` or 
`android:layout_height="56dp"`.

See [documentation](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html) about `height`.