# How to set fill items in BottomNavigationView on Android

Tags: java, android, xml, fragment, bottomnavigationview

In my application i want use `BottomNavigationView` view to show some fragments.I have **4 `fragments`** and i set this `fragments` into `BottomNavigationView`.
I write below codes but in large device screens such as Tables show me this items in center of `BottomNavigationView`.
such as below image :
[image: Image 1]

**But i want** show this items **fill of** `BottomNavigationView`, such as below image : 
[image: Image 2]

**My XML codes :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mainNavigationFragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation_graph"/>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

How can i change my codes for show items such as **image two**?

Comment: hello i think this is your answer :)
[how you fill your bottom navigation menus ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41432902/bottomnavigationview-is-not-full-width)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use `ConstraintLayout` and see whether the issue is solved

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_manager"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_graph"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: thanks dear, but your code is just set full screen for BottomNavigationView! i want set full screen items of BottomNavigationView !

Comment: my answer is similar on image 2.

Comment: yes my friend, i try your code and work me. thanks for your help <3